# python binary tree iterator - why returned node becomes None?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm scratching my head for an hour.

I implemented binary tree in-order traversal using the iterator & stack.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left, right):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class BTIterator:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.stack = []  # Use a list as a stack by using pop() & append()
        self.root = root
        self.leftmost = None

    def Run(self):
        node = self.root
        while (node.left != None):
            self.stack.append(node)
            node = node.left
        print(self.stack)
        self.leftmost = node
        print(self.leftmost.val)
        while (self.Next(node) != None):
            node = self.Next(node)
            print(node.val)

    def Next(self, node):
        if (node.left != None):
            while (node.left != None):
                self.stack.append(node.left)
                node = node.left
            return node

        elif (node.right != None):
            node = node.right
            while (node.left != None):
                self.stack.append(node)
                node = node.left
            return node

        else:
            if self.stack != []:
                node = self.stack.pop()
                node.left = None
                return node
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Let's construct the tree.
    n12 = Node(12, None, None)
    n11 = Node(11, None, n12)
    n9 = Node(9, None, None)
    n10 = Node(10, n9, n11)
    n15 = Node(15, None, None)
    n13 = Node(13, n10, n15)
    n5 = Node(5, None, None)
    n3 = Node(3, None, n5)
    n7 = Node(7, n3, n13)

    bti = BTIterator(n7)
    bti.Run()
```

I also ran above implementation on IDE. From debugging, I clearly see `def Next(self, node)` returns `n7`. However once `node = self.Next(node)` line gets the `n7`, it turns `n7` into `None`. Why?!

I think this must be a python syntax that I do not know.
Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: just from a brief glance it seems your `next` will iterate until it hits None and then returns it, i think you want to stop BEFORE you hit `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your implementation, there are three problems I want to point out:

1. the main problem is your implemtation in `Next` is incorrect. Because inorder traversal is `left->root->right`, `if (node.left != None):` part is correct, but here:

```
        elif (node.right != None):
            node = node.right
            while (node.left != None):
                self.stack.append(node)
                node = node.left
            return node
```

you should return node itself first before deal with `right` child.

```
        else:
            if self.stack != []:
                node = self.stack.pop()
                node.left = None
                return node
```

and you should not only `pop` when node is leaf, you should push every node in stack, and pop every `Next`.

2. you can not put `Next` in both while condition and block, because it will call twice.

```
while (self.Next(node) != None):
   node = self.Next(node)
```

3. `!= None` in `if (node.left != None):` is not needed in python, you can just use `if node.left:`

because `Next` has many problems, so I have to rewrited `Next`, here is the version I edited based on your code, and I have commented in details:

```
class BTIterator:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.stack = []  # Use a list as a stack by using pop() & append()
        self.root = root

    def Run(self):
        # find the left most node, which means then first node
        node = self.root
        while node.left:
            self.stack.append(node)
            node = node.left

        # start from left most node
        while node:
            print(node.val)
            node = self.Next(node)

    def Next(self, node):
        # find right node, if it is none, it's ok, we will deal with it afterwards
        node = node.right

        # reach the end
        if not self.stack and not node:
            return None

        # push left child iteratively
        while node:
            self.stack.append(node)
            node = node.left

        # this is next node we want
        return self.stack.pop()
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I fixed the #2 that you pointed out (didn't change anything else on my original code) and now it works as expected.

Comment: glad to hear that, maybe I misunderstand your algorithm, actually `Next` works